# Apache: Using %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} inside <Directory> section

Tags: apache, server, environment-variables

My virtualhost configuration file `sites-available/site.conf` contains (some lines omitted):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <Directory /var/www/html/my_website>
    # set options
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This sets the options in `my_website` directory. I can do the same with a `Define` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Define website /var/www/html/my_website
  <Directory ${website}>
    # set options
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I try the same with an Apache server variable [`%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars) the options are not set:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_website
  <Directory %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}>
    # set options
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` not working     in this case?

Comment: Did you ever get to find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I couldn't any similar example in [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html). It seems that [request variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) cannot be used in section directives.